# Gitlab ci cache is empty when on retry

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've got a problem with gitlab-ci multi runner. I have several stages in my setup. Let's pretend build, test. Build works fine, but when it comes to the test stage the job is failing because of some infrastructure issue. Then I fix the reason of failure and want to repeat only the last step assuming the cache between stages is alive. But it fails again because of the empty cache. Here is an example to demonstrate my layout

eg.

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build_step:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  cache:
    key: ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    untracked: true
    paths:
    - bld/
  script:
    - rm -rf bld
    - mkdir -p bld
    - cd bld
    - touch build_here

test:
  stage: test
  cache:
    key: ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    untracked: true
    paths:
    - bld/
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - cd bld
    - ls -all
```

Here is my gitlab-runner version:

```
# gitlab-ci-multi-runner --version
Version:      9.5.1
Git revision: 96b34cc
Git branch:   9-5-stable
GO version:   go1.8.3
Built:        Wed, 04 Oct 2017 16:26:27 +0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Cache is served on a best-effort basis; to pass data through jobs you need to use artifacts, as it explained in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/caching/index.html#cache-vs-artifacts):

> - `cache` - **Use for temporary storage for project dependencies**. Not useful for keeping intermediate build results, like jar or apk files. Cache was designed to be used to speed up invocations of subsequent runs of a given job, by keeping things like dependencies (e.g., npm packages, Go vendor packages, etc.) so they don't have to be re-fetched from the public internet. While the cache can be abused to pass intermediate build results between stages, there may be cases where artifacts are a better fit.
> - `artifacts` - **Use for stage results that will be passed between stages**. Artifacts were designed to upload some compiled/generated bits of the build, and they can be fetched by any number of concurrent Runners. They are guaranteed to be available and are there to pass data between jobs. They are also exposed to be downloaded from the UI.

You need to use [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#dependencies) along with [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts) to obtain what you want